# Read / Write of files which may be in use by other software

Tags: files-and-directories, output, input

I am using Mathematica 10.3.1.0 on a Raspberry Pi.
I would like Mathematica to open, read from, write to and close a file which may sometimes also be accessed by some external software.
I created the file "dead_letter_box.txt" in "Text Editor", saved it and closed the Text Editor. The following code then worked exactly as expected:

```
compactreadfile[filename_, fileextension_] := 
Module[{filelocation, file, contentsoffile},
filelocation = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], StringJoin[filename, fileextension]}];
contentsoffile = {};
If[FileExistsQ[filelocation],
 file = OpenRead[filelocation];
 contentsoffile = ReadList[file];
 Print[contentsoffile];
 Close[file];,
 Print["The file does not exist"]
 ]
]

compactwritefile[filename_, fileextension_, contentsoffile_] := 
Module[{filelocation, file},
filelocation = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],StringJoin[filename, fileextension]}];
If[FileExistsQ[filelocation],
 file = OpenWrite[filelocation];
 Write[file, contentsoffile];
 Close[file];,
 Print["The file does not exist"]
 ]
]

filename = "dead_letter_box";
fileextension = ".txt";
compactreadfile[filename, fileextension]

filename = "dead_letter_box";
fileextension = ".txt";
variable = 7;
compactwritefile[filename, fileextension, variable]

filename = "dead_letter_box";
fileextension = ".txt";
compactreadfile[filename, fileextension]
```

That is, the first read produced the output {}, the write produced no ouput, and the second read produced the output {7}. Moreover, when I opened the text file in the Text Editor, it contained the single character 7, as expected.

My problem is that these tests give exactly the same results, when I leave the text file open in the Text Editor. I had hoped Mathematica would return an error message, to the effect that the file is already in use by another program.

Is there a way to make Mathematica generate such errors ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking that a file is in use by another application is very operating system dependent. As far as I know, Mahtematica doesn't support testing for this in user code.

Reading in a file that is in use by another app is harmless in itself. `OpenWrite` can be dangerous because it always deletes any pre-existing file before proceeding. So perhaps you should change the strategy you use in `compactwritefile` to

1. Refuse to write out to a file that already exists because `OpenWrite` always deletes any pre-existing file.
2. Make sure you close the file that you are writing to no matter what happens.

Here is a version of `compactwritefile` that uses this strategy.

```
compactwritefile[filename_, contentsoffile_] := 
  Module[{filelocation, file}, 
    filelocation = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", filename}];
    If[FileExistsQ[filelocation],
      Print["The file already exists"],
      file = OpenWrite[filelocation];
      If[file === $Failed,
        Print["Could not open file"],
        AbortProtect[
          Write[file, contentsoffile];
          Close[file]]]]]
```

First test.

```
compactwritefile["test.txt", "This is another test."]
```

> `/Users/oldmg/Desktop/test.txt`

Second test.

```
compactwritefile["test.txt", "This is a test."]
```

> `The file already exists`

#### Implementation notes

1. I think it is easier to omit the file extension as separated argument and let `FileNameJoin` do the string concatenation.
2. `AbortProtect` forces the file to be closed even it the write operation causes an abort condition.
3. It is good to test that the file has really opened before proceeding.